# Parse HTML in Scala

Tags: html, xml, scala, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Task: HTML - Parser in Scala. Im pretty new to scala.

So far: I have written a little Parser in Scala to parse a random html document.

```
import scala.xml.Elem
import scala.xml.Node
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
import scala.xml.Text
import scala.xml.PrettyPrinter

object Reader {
  def loadXML = {
    val parserFactory = new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXFactoryImpl
    val parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser()
    val source = new org.xml.sax.InputSource("http://www.randomurl.com")
    val adapter = new scala.xml.parsing.NoBindingFactoryAdapter
    val feed = adapter.loadXML(source, parser)
    feed
  }

  def proc(node: Node): String =
    node match {
      case <body>{ txt }</body> => "Partial content: " + txt
      case _ => "grmpf"
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val content = Reader.loadXML
    Console.println(content)
    Console.println(proc(content))

  }
}
```

1. The problem is that the "proc" does not work. Basically, I would like to get exactly the content of one node. Or is there another way to achieve that without matching?
2. Does the "feed" in the loadxml-function give me back the right format for parsing or is there a better way to achieve that? Feed gives me back the root node, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Parsing HTML as XML is never a good idea. There are some nice Java libs for that purpose. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is one of them.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: That's why the asker is using the TagSoup parser, which gives you a nice SAX interface to non-XML HTML.

Comment: @TravisBrown Oh, ok. Didn't notice that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: `adapter.loadXML(source, parser)` gives you the root node. The problem is that that root node probably isn't going to match the `body` case in  in your `proc` method. Even if the root node were `body`, it still wouldn't match unless the element contained nothing but text.

You probably want something more like this:

```
def proc(node: Node): String = (node \\ "body").text
```

Where `\\` is a selector method that's roughly equivalent to XPath's `//`—i.e., it returns all the descendants of `node` named `body`. If you know that `body` is a child (as opposed to a deeper descendant) of the root node, which is probably the case for HTML, you can use `\` instead of `\\`.

Comment: Thx a lot travis :). May I ask an additional question...Is there a way to give me all nodes in a hierarchy like a tree? Do I have to do this recursive or is there another way? I mean like i.e. 
html
-head
-body
--div1
--div2

Thx in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `Node` (or more specifically `Elem`) does give you a tree—it has a `child` method that returns its children, although it's usually easier to use the selectors to navigate the tree.